# Eclipse debugger: hot code replace failed for server wilfly 20

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss, wildfly

When I am running eclipse wildfly server in debug mode, and do minor change in the code, i get the following 2 dialogs in eclipse (find screenshot):
[image]

eclipse/project/Build automatically is ticked.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What minor change? Removing a method or changing the signature of a method is not a minor change (`contains obsolete methods`). Do you get this while one or more threads are paused? What exactly is your issue? The dialog tells the problem and provides the options you have. So what's wrong with that?

Comment: WildFLy classloading doesn't allow for jpda hot replace. Please use Jboss tools for this.